# Copied Skyrim Save File can't Save on other profile

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

I was playing Skyrim on my brother's PS3 account and I created my own PS3 account so I tried to copy the file from his PS3 account to mine.  It worked and I could load the game but it says since the game was created on a different account it can't be saved and the trophies can't be loaded.

I tried using autosave but it doesn't work.  The Save option in the menu is disabled.  I'm kinda far in the game and I really don't wanna start over... there *has* to be a way to do this.

Is there?

Comment: I can not give a 100% answer because I did not make the game but I do recall that PS3 save files, if they included the trophy information as well, were always tied to a specific user account. I am actually a bit surprised the file loaded.. All I can think of is that when it tries to save its including the trophies file and failing, but when it tries to load it is only getting the game data and so works. Again, this is just speculation so not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The PS3 won't let you because it considers that cheating. You could try calling Playstation and appealing to them for help, but I would just bite the bullet and start a new game.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to download his account onto your PS3 and use that to play the save file. Play offline so both instances of his account aren't online at the same time. This shouldn't effect gameplay because Skyrim doesn't feature online play.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I know it's a little convoluted, but it works. You HAVE to play the saved game from the profile that first saved it.

Just move it back to the "owner" profile when you want to play it. If you want to get it out of the way when you're done, move it back into the new profile you copied it into to begin with.

Might as well just leave the game in the profile that originally saved it.

Answer (score 0):

you could download bruteforce and change the info of the save to your own, this would make it work for your ps3 or another account.

Comment: Consider adding steps to make this happen. A link to bruteforce as well would help him find the right program.